# Which case to use in this sentence 'Wir können auch in die Natur spazieren gehen '

Tags: translation

I thought it should be "die Natur" as Natur is the direct object? I am a beginner so check the sentence with translation apps and they say it should be "der Natur", but I'm not sure why it would be "der"?

Thank you for your help

Comment: *Natur* cannot be the direct object because it is preceded by a **preposition**.

Comment: You shouldn't think in terms of *direct* and *indirect* object. There's nothing like that in German.

Comment: @Olafant every resource I am using refers to the indirect, direct object and the subject of a sentence in German

Comment: @AliceDent That analogy tends to work for a while for beginners. But as soon as sentences become sufficiently complex, it tends to do more harm than good to understanding. Use *direct* and *indirect object* for starters, but be aware you are oversimplifying things. You should accomodate to the concept of *dative*, *genitive* and *accusative* (sometimes even *nominative*) objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"in" is a preposition, which actually rules either the accusative (expressing a direction towards or into something), or the dative (expressing movement within a certain area, like the English "in").

In your example, "Natur" can either be accusative or dative, depending what you want to say:

*Wir gehen in die Natur spazieren* (acc) - We move from somewhere outside **into** nature.

*Wir gehen in der Natur spazieren* (dat) - we move about **within** nature.

Comment: thank you! This is really helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can actually say both, but with different meanings.

**Akkusativ:**

> Wir können auch in die Natur spazieren gehen.

means that you can walk into nature, while at the point of offering to do so, not being in nature.

**Dativ:**

> Wir können auch in der Natur spazieren gehen.

How this sentence doesn't say, at the point of offering to do so, if you're already there (in nature) or not.

Comment: In the example, *Natur* is actually accusative.

Comment: Yes you're correct. I updated my answer to hopefully make it more understandable and correct

Comment: thank you tonitiger!

Comment: @AliceDent if one of those answers helped you, don't forget to mark the one that helped you the most as accepted :)

Comment: thank you! I wasn't sure how to do that but found it now, wish I could accept both though, thank you for your help